# How can I report broken functionality to Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug

I've encountered a rendering issue while browsing Stack Overflow. How do I report this to the development team?

Specifically:

1. When creating a title for a question and double checking for duplicates, wait for results to appear.
2. Change a word in the title, wait for the new result set to appear.
3. Scroll. The old results will remain there, although immobile, while the new results scroll, superimposed onto each other, making it hard to read.

See screenshot below:

[image: Bug screenshot]

Comment: You report bugs by posting questions on meta, like this one.

Comment: I was going to say you should check for duplicates, but... 

Comment: Seems like Firefox is the common element (I'm on MacOS 10.15).
Those are from 7/8 months ago. Guessing the fix isn't coming soon :)

Comment: For security vulnerabilities and other things that shouldn't be shared in public, use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page. For everything else, use Meta.

Comment: What browser, what version, and on what platform? Firefox 78.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 MATE/[Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment))?